# Multi-thread can't join properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
condition_variable cov;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
void showNum(int &f_, atomic_bool &alive_)
{
    while(alive_)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        cov.wait(lk,[]{ return ready;});
        f_++;
        ready = false;
        processed= true;
        lk.unlock();
        cout<<f_<<endl;
        cov.notify_one();
    }

}
int main() {
    vector<int> va;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        va.push_back(i);
    }
    int f = 0;
    atomic_bool alive{ true };


    std::thread t1(showNum,ref(f),ref(alive));
    auto sizeofVector = va.size();
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeofVector; ++j) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk0(m);
            f = va.back();
            cout<<f<<"    ";
            ready = true;
        }

        cov.notify_one();
        va.pop_back();
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
            cov.wait(lk,[]{return processed;});
            processed = false;
            lk.unlock();
        }

    }

    alive = false;
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to test the condition variable in multi-thread.
The code above is my test code.

the error is that the thread t1 can't join properly. I print the `alive_`, it is always true, can't be set to false by `alive = false` in the main thread.

I try to make `alive` a global variable, but still the same error.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: [Rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to know what wakes up the thread after `alive` is set to false.

Comment: As the @Christophe said, the thread t1 is stuck on the code cov.wait(lk,[]{ return ready;}); when the main thread set the alive to be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be changed

```
cov.wait(lk,[]{ return ready;});
```

to

```
cov.wait(lk,[&alive_]{ return ready || !alive_;});
if (!alive_)
    break;
```

And below `alive_=false;` add the line

```
cov.notify_one();
```

The complete code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
condition_variable cov;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
void showNum(int &f_, atomic_bool &alive_)
{
    while(alive_)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        cov.wait(lk,[&alive_]{return ready || !alive_;});
        if (!alive_)
            break;
        f_++;
        ready = false;
        processed= true;
        lk.unlock();
        cout<<f_<<endl;
        cov.notify_one();
    }

}
int main() {
    vector<int> va;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        va.push_back(i);
    }
    int f = 0;
    atomic_bool alive{ true };


    std::thread t1(showNum,ref(f),ref(alive));
    auto sizeofVector = va.size();
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeofVector; ++j) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk0(m);
            f = va.back();
            cout<<f<<"    ";
            ready = true;
        }

        cov.notify_one();
        va.pop_back();
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
            cov.wait(lk,[]{return processed;});
            processed = false;
            lk.unlock();
        }

    }

    alive = false;
    cov.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ccxxshow, Thanks for your advice. I tried it and it works.

Comment: But there is some problem with your code. I find the predicate can't be the parameter that income to the `showNum()`, so the `cov.wait(lk,[&alive_]{return ready || !alive_;});` will occur error because of the `alive_` is the parameter of `showNom()`. When I modify it to the global parameter `alive`, it passes.

Comment: What error was reported, is  'alive_' not capture? What version is your g++

Comment: yes, 'alive_' not capture， g++ version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 1):

In `t1` the function doesn't constantly test `alive`.  You have designed it so that every loop starts with waiting on the condition variable.  It then go sleep and wakeup only when notified. Unfortunately, when main sets alive to false, the t1 thread is still in a waiting state.

You can observe this easily:

```
void showNum(int &f_, atomic_bool &alive_)
{
    while(alive_)
    {   cout<<"waiting..."<<endl;   
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        cout<<"waiting more..."<<endl;
        cov.wait(lk,[]{ return ready;});  ///<<<<< stuck here 
        cout<<"go..."<<endl;
        f_++;
        ready = false;
        processed= true;
        lk.unlock();
        cout<<"  sn:"<<f_<<endl;
        cov.notify_one();
    }
}
```

It will wake up only if `main` would ensure one more notifification on the condition variable.  Only at this moment would it exit from its waiting state, and after processing find out that `alive` is `false` .

To avoid being stuck forever, you could change your code and make use of [`wait_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) so that the function can check on time out if it should still stay `alive`.

Comment: In addition you need to set `ready` to `true`. Otherwise T1 will immediately go back to sleep. Have a look at the [condition_variable::wait](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) function with predicate.

Comment: @julians good point ! There should be a predicate. But the spurious wakeup is a risk and not a feature (more [here](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables)). So the predicate is IMHO not a replacement for the timeout, is it?

Comment: I don't think it is a replacement for a timeout. As far as I understood it, without the predicate returning true, T1 won't wake up. Even if it notified. (This is also what I could observe when testing the code)

Comment: @Christophe,@julians, Thanks for providing me your advice. wait_for is a choice to solve the problem, but a suit time interval should be used. Maybe it is not that elegant. My humble opinion.

Comment: @tingdazhuang Indeed, the timeout is not the most elegant approach. The clean way would be to implement the paragraphe just before the one on wait_for: ensure that the main would notify once more the waiting thread so that it can realize that it’s over.

Comment: @Christophe, yard, I add a notify_one() at the end of the main thread. I will answer the question again to show my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
condition_variable cov;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
atomic_bool alive{ true };
void showNum(int &f_, atomic_bool &alive_)
{
    while(alive)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        cov.wait(lk,[]{ return ready || !alive;});
        if(!alive)
            break;
        f_++;
        ready = false;
        processed= true;
        lk.unlock();
        cout<<f_<<endl;
        cov.notify_one();
    }

}
int main() {
    vector<int> va;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        va.push_back(i);
    }
    int f = 0;



    std::thread t1(showNum,ref(f),ref(alive));
    auto sizeofVector = va.size();
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeofVector; ++j) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk0(m);
            f = va.back();
            cout<<f<<"    ";
            ready = true;
        }

        cov.notify_one();
        va.pop_back();
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
            cov.wait(lk,[]{return processed;});
            processed = false;
            lk.unlock();
        }

    }
    alive = false;
    cov.notify_one();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Integrating the advice, I modify my code to be above. It output as I expected.
Thanks for all the people provide the advice, best regards.